# java -jar: What's the default class path?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, manifest

In a jar file, `MANIFEST.mf` contains following line:

style A:

```
Class-Path: .
```

style B:

```
Class-Path: . eric-java-util_lib/tomcat-api.jar
```

style C:

```
// No `Class-Path` specified.
```

**Questions:**

1. In style B, is the jar specified by `Class-Path` related to residing dir of current jar?
2. Then in style A and B, what does `.` mean? Is it uncompressed root dir of jar, or the residing dir of current jar? I guess it should be the later, but not sure.
3. It seems classes & packages besides `MANIFEST.mf` are also included in classpath in all the 3 styles, is it due to `.`? Or, the default classpath for `java -jar` is just the root dir of uncompress jar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***As you are using*** `java -jar`, the following applies:

> In style B, is the jar specified by Class-Path related to residing dir of current jar?

It is related to the 'residing dir of current jar' in all styles.

> Then in style A and B, what does . mean?

It means the directory where the .jar file is located.

> Is it uncompressed root dir of jar

No.

> or the residing dir of current jar?

Yes.

> I guess it should be the later, but not sure.

Yes. Be sure.

> It seems classes & packages besides MANIFEST.mf are also included in classpath in all the 3 styles, is it due to .?

I don't know what 'besides MANIFEST.mf' means.

> Or, the default classpath for java -jar is just the root dir of uncompress jar file?

There is no default classpath for `java -jar` other than the .jar file itself and whatever is specified in the `Class-Path` manifest entry.

Comment: I did more test, all your conclusion meet the testing result. About the default classpath, the root dir of uncompressed jar is included in the classpath, and I guess that's just what the jar basically means.

Answer (score 0):

> In style B, is the jar specified by `Class-Path` related to residing dir of current jar?

Yes it is (See Java SE Documentation note below).

> Then in style A and B, what does `.` mean? Is it uncompressed root dir of jar, or the residing dir of current jar? I guess it should be the later, but not sure.

It is the residing directory of the jar (See Java SE Documentation below).

> It seems classes & packages besides `MANIFEST.mf` are also included in classpath in all the 3 styles, is it due to `.`? Or, the default classpath for `java -jar` is just the root dir of uncompress jar file?

As stated in [Java SE Documentation: How the Java Launcher Finds User Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html):

> The default value, ".", meaning that user class files are all the class files in the current directory (or under it, if in a package).
>
> ...
>
> The JAR archive specified by the -jar option, which overrides all other values. If this option is used, all user classes must come from the specified archive.

Comment: Your link refers to the 'user class path', which is ignored when you use `java -jar`.

Comment: That's why it's additional information, not the part of the answer. Is that the reason of the down vote?

Comment: Your 'additional information' merely states that you 'read an article', without even citing it. It isn't of any value or relevance and it isn't part of what I am commenting on, which clearly *is* part of your answer.

Comment: I understand, and you deleted it, now is not in the answer and it is still down voted.

Comment: I deleted nothing, and the error that I commented on is still present. Your point eludes me.

Comment: The link was not available. I understand your point and I deleted that part myself. What I mean is that fixing an answer or commenting it, so it can be improved is better than a down vote. But you are in your right to do you what you think is best.

Comment: And *when* you've fixed it, I *may* consider it. But you haven't. The link is available now. After I fixed it for you. And it is still irrelevant, for the reasons I stated. All this stuff about 'additional information' has nothing to do with it, and never did.

Comment: I understand what you mean now. The link was intentionally that way because you have to search for that section, it does not goes directly there. If you read the linked page you will see the following statement "The JAR archive specified by the -jar option, which overrides all other values. If this option is used, all user classes must come from the specified archive." My link is, as well, the official documentation on the topic.

Comment: I **have** read the section you now mention, some 20 years ago, and I am relying on it, here, under another answer, and in my own. It means that the quotation you have cited about 'the default value' is irrelevant. Which is what I said in the first place.

Comment: I **have** also read the section I've been mentioning from the beginning, an hour ago the last time. I quote the part about 'the default value' because is relevant to the first and second answers, where I referenced it. But, I respect your opinion, although, I disagree.

Comment: The part about the default value isn't relevant to anything in this question, because he is using `java -jar`, as stated in  your latest addition to your answer, which I stated 50 minutes ago. You are now contradicting yourself.

Comment: Your comments did improve the answer, though. That's what this is about. But from what I see we don't understand the question the same way. That's why we both wrote different answers.

Comment: The quotation about the default value is irrelevant, *because of the quotation that immediately follows it.* It's a self-contradiction. No 'interpretation' required. All you have to do is delete it. Not difficult.

Comment: I won't tell you what you have to do. I hope it will be useful to someone.

Comment: @acm I did more test, your answer to first 2 questions are correct. About the last question, In my test, `.` is not the default value of `Class-Path`, need to specify it explicitly.